# String array as comma separated string in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

How I can set value of string[] property in xaml?

I hava control with next property: string[] PropName

I want to set value of this property in next way:

```
<ns:SomeControl PropName="Val1,Val2" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [the `<x:Array>` markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752340.aspx), but its syntax is quite verbose.

Another option is to create your own `TypeConverter` that can convert from the comma-separated list to an array:

```cs
class ArrayTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFrom(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        string list = value as string;
        if (list != null)
            return list.Split(',');

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
}
```

If the type you were converting to was your type, you could then apply [the `[TypeConverter]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute.aspx) to that type. But since you want to convert to `string[]`, you can't do that. So you have to apply that attribute to all properties where you want to use this converter:

```cs
[TypeConverter(typeof(ArrayTypeConverter))]
public string[] PropName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

```xml
     <ns:SomeControl>
        <SomeControl.PropName>
            <x:Array Type="sys:String">
                <sys:String>Val1</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Val2</sys:String>
            </x:Array> 
        </SomeControl.PropName>
    </ns:SomeControl>
```

Comment: +1. I just realized that you proposed this answer in sll's comments way before I wrote mine.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to define custom values as Array in resources of a control/window and then just use Binding to a static resource:

```
<!-- or Window.Resources -->
<UserControl.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="CustomValues" 
             Type="sys:String"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"> 
        <sys:String>Val1</sys:String> 
        <sys:String>Val2</sys:String> 
    </x:Array> 
</UserControl.Resources>

<!-- Then just bind -->
<ns:SomeControl PropName="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomValues}}" />
```

Comment: Why binding to `StaticResource`? Why resource at all?

Comment: +1, this is the way to go for values known at compile time. Now if he needs dynamic values (runtime values, bound, etc) he's going to need an I(Multi)ValueConverter that returns an array.

Comment: @Snowbear : this is what I know for now, I would appreciate any more advanced solution, why you've deleted your answer and do not provided an answer? Really I've no other idea how to do it so would +1 if you show an other way, thanks in advance

Comment: @sll, I deleted my answer because it is formatted weirdly due to some unknown reason, trying to figure that out right now

Comment: I know all values at compile time, so do not need to bind any dynamic values.

Comment: @Snowbear : undelete it and I will help you formatting it properly

Comment: Any ways to do same things without Binding and Resources?

Comment: Using this approach, one can add `sys:String` values directly to PropName instead of some Array.

Comment: @sll, I think he means something like `<ns:SomeControl><ns:SomeControl.PropName><x:Array>…</x:Array></ns:SomeControl.PropName></ns:SomeControl>`.

Comment: @sll, did it, please take a look

Comment: @Snowbear : looks like it was some bug in formatting of your answer since formatting behave weird, now looks better but I've no idea what was the problem

Comment: @Snowbear : Only one diference I found is incresed left padding of the code block

Answer (score 2):

[sll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8414023/87698) is great, but you can avoid the resource if you want and write the value directly into the control:

```
<ns:SomeControl>
    <ns:SomeControl.PropName>
        <x:Array Type="sys:String" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                 xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">  
            <sys:String>Val1</sys:String>  
            <sys:String>Val2</sys:String>  
        </x:Array>  
    </ns:SomeControl.PropName>
</ns:SomeControl>
```

In addition, you can move the `xmlns:` declarations into the head element (Window, UserControl, etc.), so you don't clutter your control properties with it.

PS: If you are the one developing `SomeControl`, I'd use [svick's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8414229/87698) and provide a TypeConverter.

Comment: The `x:Key` is redundant when it's not a resource.